# Wordpress Dropdown not working correctly - CSS issue?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

Hi I have been breaking my head trying to figure out why is it that the drop-down on this page I am working on looks weird. I am pretty sure it is a CSS issue but I have tried debugging with Firebug and can't seem to find a solution.

Here is the link to the site:
goo.gl/HXabQv

As you can see, the sub-menu is pretty much acting the same as the main menu items and not displaying how a drop down should actually look. Highly appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: please post code here or provide a jsfiddle....

Comment: how can I add it from wordpress?

Comment: Your styles certainly are a bit of a disaster. How do you want this laid out?

Comment: goo.gl/HXabQv this is the link to the page and you will see the actual nav bar messed up. The drop-down is visible and not working at all. You can inspect element or use firebug

Comment: @ralph.m As basic as possible. Something like this will work for me:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7fjb0a181rvyzk/drop-down-example.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the full code you would need, but it's a starting point for cleaning things up:

```
ol#menu-main_menu a:hover {color: white; text-decoration: underline;}
ol#menu-main_menu ul a, ol#menu-main_menu ul a:hover {color: black;}
ol#menu-main_menu li {position: relative}
ol#menu-main_menu li ul {position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 20px; list-style: bullet; background: white;}
ol#menu-main_menu li:hover ul {left: 0;}
ol#menu-main_menu li ul li {width: 100px; border: 0;}
```

Comment: that worked smoothly, I'll take care of styling the rest. You said this isn't the full code I'll need but what's missing if it's working properly?

Comment: `what's missing if it's working properly?` Nothing. :-) I just thought you'd want to style it a bit more.

Comment: haha yeah I added some basic styling. kept it nice and simple and lowered the drop-down a bit to align with the blue border on the bottom.... peep it: goo.gl/HXabQv

Comment: Not bad, although I see white text on a gray background in the sub menus, and the current style on the main menu make the link a bit hard to see (blue on a blue background).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that myself. Trying to finish fixing this dropdown completely. How would I add a 3rd child drop-down box but that goes to the right side?? Thanks for your help!